# How to combine two files sequentially based on certain conditions in Unix

Tags: unix, rhel

I am trying to format files in Unix (In this case RHEL).

File 1

```
AAAAA|AAA|1582|YNYY
BBBBB|BAV|1234|NYYY
```

File 1 has 1 sample record (row). There are 4 columns in each record. In Column 4 we have 4 status values.

File 2

```
20190103|W 2019 01
20190203|W 2019 02
20190303|W 2019 03
20190403|W 2019 04
```

Output has to be as follows:

```
AAAAA|1582|Y|20190103|W 2019 01
AAAAA|1582|N|20190203|W 2019 02
AAAAA|1582|Y|20190303|W 2019 03
AAAAA|1582|Y|20190403|W 2019 04
BBBBB|1234|N|20190103|W 2019 01
BBBBB|1234|Y|20190203|W 2019 02
BBBBB|1234|Y|20190303|W 2019 03
BBBBB|1234|Y|20190403|W 2019 04
```

I have tried AWK and Paste but am not able to get the required output.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F'|' '{split($4,a,""); b=$1"|"$2"|"$3} { getline < "file2"; for (i in a ) print b"|"a[i]"|"$0  }' < file1`
```

Demo:

```
$cat file1 file2 
AAAAA|AAA|1582|YNYY
BBBBB|BAV|1234|NYYY
20190103|W 2019 01
20190203|W 2019 02
20190303|W 2019 03
20190403|W 2019 04
$awk -F'|' '{split($4,a,""); b=$1"|"$2"|"$3} { getline < "file2"; for (i in a ) print b"|"a[i]"|"$0  }' < file1
AAAAA|AAA|1582|Y|20190103|W 2019 01
AAAAA|AAA|1582|N|20190103|W 2019 01
AAAAA|AAA|1582|Y|20190103|W 2019 01
AAAAA|AAA|1582|Y|20190103|W 2019 01
BBBBB|BAV|1234|N|20190203|W 2019 02
BBBBB|BAV|1234|Y|20190203|W 2019 02
BBBBB|BAV|1234|Y|20190203|W 2019 02
BBBBB|BAV|1234|Y|20190203|W 2019 02
$
```

Explanation:

`awk -F'|'` <-- Set field seprator as |

`'{split($4,a,"");` <-- Split 4th  field and store in  array a

`b=$1"|"$2"|"$3}` <-- Store Column 1-2 in variable b

`getline < "file2";` <-- read input from file2 row by row

`for (i in a ) print b"|"a[i]"|"$0` <--  Loop through array `a` and append variable `b` and input record from `file2`

Note: When you use `getline` value of internal variables `$0, NF, NR` get changed

Comment: Thank you Digvijay

Comment: But can u help me to get Output in the following format

Comment: AAAAA|1582|Y|20190103|W 2019 01
AAAAA|1582|N|20190203|W 2019 02
AAAAA|1582|Y|20190303|W 2019 03
AAAAA|1582|Y|20190403|W 2019 04
BBBBB|1234|N|20190103|W 2019 01
BBBBB|1234|Y|20190203|W 2019 02
BBBBB|1234|Y|20190303|W 2019 03
BBBBB|1234|Y|20190403|W 2019 04

Comment: first record in file1 should be matched with all the records in the file2

Comment: You don't want second column from first file right ?

Comment: try this `awk -F'|' '{split($4,a,""); b=$1"|"$3} { getline < "file2"; for (i in a ) print b"|"a[i]"|"$0  }' < file1`
`

Comment: Hi Digvijay,  the output should be like for every record in file1 based on the number of chars in 4th column that many records have to be created for each record in file1 and that record has to be mapped with the records in file2

Comment: file1 a|b|c|ynyn

Comment: file2 e|f         o/p: a|b|c|y|e|f